# Responsive 3-column page last column jumps down when very narrow window

Tags: css, responsive-design

The html is:

```
<div id="container">

<div id="top-bar">Top Bar</div>    
<div id="nav-bar">
    <a>Blah 1</a>
    <a>Blah 2</a>
    <a>Blah 3</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
    <div id="column-left">
        column left
    </div>
    <div id="column-right">
        column right
    </div>
     <div id="column-right-adsense">
        column right adsense
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>

<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

and the css is:

```
#container {
/* width: 500px; */
border: 1px solid black;
}

#top-bar {
height:60px;
border: 1px solid red;    
}

#column-left {
border: 1px solid blue;    
width: 40%; /* 200 / 500 */
 float: left;
}

#column-right {
    border: 1px solid yellow;    
    width: 40%; /* 200 / 500 */
    float: left;
}
#column-right-adsense {
        border: 1px solid cyan;    
width: 18%; /* 90 / 500 */
 float: left;

}

.spacer {
    clear:both;
}
```

As you can see on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbel/cVdwE/) when you resize the window narrow the last column jumps down. How can I prevent that?

Comment: Are the borders just for demonstration purposes?

Comment: Yeah, the borders are for demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

You could checkout something like bootstrap.js which would help with creating a page like that.

[Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

Answer (score 0):

Its fixed here,

Check, http://jsfiddle.net/cVdwE/2/

```
#column-left {
border: 1px solid blue;     margin:-1px;
width: 40%; /* 200 / 500 */
 float: left;
}

#column-right {
    border: 1px solid yellow;   margin:-1px;  
    width: 40%; /* 200 / 500 */
    float: left;
}
#column-right-adsense {
        border: 1px solid cyan;   margin:-1px;  
width: 20%; /* 90 / 500 */
 float: left;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the 1px solid border.

You can fix with in two different ways:

1. Remove `width: 18%;` and `float: left;` from the third column and add `overflow: hidden;`
2. Add `box-sizing` to the three columns

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/5666G/

You should definitely read about the [CSS Box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) and [Float containment](http://colinaarts.com/articles/float-containment/)